# Sort Javascript array of objects by greatest value

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects where an object can look like this:

```
{
    "id": "d630baff-0caf-4c9a-88a2-fc4c99fab2a4",
    "created": "2021-01-24 20:27:28",
    "last_updated": "2021-01-20 13:17:44"
}
```

I want to sort based on either value that is largest of `created` or `last_updated`. I'm able to perform this in SQL by querying `ORDER BY GREATEST(created, last_updated) DESC`, but how would I achieve this in Javascript? I have tried doing `objs.sort((a, b) => (a.created > b.last_updated) ? 1 : -1)` but it doesn't result in the right order.

Comment: Try to parse does "created" and "last_updated" to Date object of javascript.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

Answer (score 0):

You could select the greater [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date

```js
const
    greatest = (a, b) => a >= b ? a : b,
    object = {
        id: "d630baff-0caf-4c9a-88a2-fc4c99fab2a4",
        created:      "2021-01-24 20:27:28",
        last_updated: "2021-01-20 13:17:44"
    }

console.log(greatest(object.created, object.last_updated));
```

and then sort by

```
array.sort((a, b) => greatest(a.created, a.last_updated)
    .localeCompare(greatest(b.created, b.last_updated)
)
```

Comment: just replace `a` and `b`.